# Multiline matching and parsing

Tags: regex, perl, multiline

I have some data I need to parse that is on multiple lines.  I would like to have certain points of the data on one line to create a table like structure out of it.  The data varies.  Some is broken up on more than one line, and some is simply just 2 lines.

**Sample Data**

Scenario 1:

```
Start Anchor - First parse boundary
Name1 - Only one line of name
12345 - Number line needed
ending anchor - End parse boundary
data
data
data
```

---

Scenario 2:

```
Start Anchor
name1 - Two lines of name.
name2
12345987
ending anchor
data
data
data
```

---

**Desired Results**

Scenario 1:

```
Name1  12345
data
data
data
```

---

Scenario 2:

```
name1 name2  12345987
data
data
data
```

---

**Explanation**

So in this data, I need the name or names and their corresponding number on the same line.  I would like to replace the `\n` for what is between the parse boundaries while still keeping the rest of the data.

**my Current results**

---

Scenario 1:

```
name1 12345987 - easy because only 1 line of name
data
data
```

---

Scenario 2:

```
name1 name2 - tough part
12345987
data
data
```

---

Code

```
my $text = read_file( 'list_2.txt' );
use File::Slurp;
$text =~ s/^Start Anchor\n(.*?)\n(.*?)ending anchor/$1 $2/gism;
print $text;
print;
```

In my eyes, `$1` variable should be capturing the name(s) because of the use of the ending anchor.  The `$2` variable should capture the number because it is always one line above the ending anchor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the non-greedy wildcards that are defeating you. The pattern `^Start Anchor\n(.*?)\n(.*?)ending anchor` will match as *few* characters as possible after `Start Anchor\n` to the next newline, which is the *first* name line. Then the next capture will match from -- again as few characters as possible, but is makes no difference here -- to `ending anchor`, whiuch is the second name line and the number, together with the newline between them because you have the `/s` modifier in effect.

It is rarely a simple job parsing an entire file in memory, and usually a better option is to read line-by line and keep state data to remember where you are in the structure.

In this case a simple nested read loop will do the trick. You don't say whether multiple blocks can appear in the same file, but this solution handles that situation as I think you would want it.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @name;

while (<DATA>) {
  if (/^Start Anchor/) {
    while (<DATA>) {
      last if /^ending anchor/;
      chomp;
      push @name, $_;
    }
    print "@name\n";
    @name = ()
  }
  else {
    print;
  }
}

__DATA__
Start Anchor
Name1
12345
ending anchor
data
data
data

Start Anchor
name1
name2
12345987
ending anchor
data
data
data
```

**output**

```
Name1 12345
data
data
data

name1 name2 12345987
data
data
data
```

Comment: So the nested loop says if there is a starting anchor that has an ending anchor chomp or remove new line on everything in between them.  Then print the whole line and a return, else print as is. @Borodin

Comment: @JDE876: Yes. Just copy lines until you find a starting anchor; read lines and push them onto `@name` until the ending anchor turns up; print the contents of `@name` on a single line, empty it, and resume copying.

Answer (score 0):

You can still process the file line by line, just remember in what state or phase you currently are:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $state = 'search anchor';
my @names;
while (<DATA>) {
    if ('search anchor' eq $state and /Start Anchor/) {
        $state = 'collect names';

    } elsif ('collect names' eq $state) {

        chomp;
        push @names, $_;

        $state = 'expect ending anchor' if /^[0-9]+$/;

    } elsif ('expect ending anchor' eq $state) {

        die 'Ending anchor not found' unless /ending anchor/;
        $state = 'data';
        print "@names\n"

    } elsif ('data' eq $state) {

        if (/Start Anchor/) {
            $state = 'collect names';
            @names = ();

        } else {
            print;
        }
    }
}

__DATA__
Start Anchor
Name1
12345
ending anchor
data
data
data

Start Anchor
name1
name2
12345987
ending anchor
data
data
data
```

Comment: `undef @names` forces the memory allocation to the array to be freed, which is probably not what you want. A simple `@names = ()` will empty the array but leave the space allocated, and is the usual preference.

Comment: @Borodin: true. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

The second name is optional.
The regex uses the eval modifier to do formatting of the substitution.
Its not really necessary, it could be done with just a replacement of `$1 $2 $3\n` if needed.

```
 # /(?xm)^Start\ Anchor\n\s*^(\w.*)\n(?:^(\w.*)\n)?\s*^(\d+).*\n\s*^ending\ anchor(?:\n|$)/

 (?xm-)
 ^ Start\ Anchor \n 
 \s* 
 ^ 
 ( \w .* )                          # (1), Name1 required
 \n 
 (?:
      ^ 
      ( \w .* )                     # (2), Name2 optional
      \n 
 )?
 \s* 
 ^ 
 ( \d+ )                            # (3), Numbers
 .* \n 
 \s* 
 ^ ending\ anchor
 (?: \n | $ )
```

Perl code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

$/ = undef;

my $data = <DATA>;

$data =~ 
   s/
     ^Start\ Anchor\n\s*^(\w.*)\n(?:^(\w.*)\n)?\s*^(\d+).*\n\s*^ending\ anchor(?:\n|$)
    /
     "$1 ".(defined $2 ? "$2 " : "") . "$3\n"
    /exmg;

print $data, "\n";

__DATA__

Start Anchor
name1
12345
ending anchor
data
data
data


Start Anchor
name1
name2
12345987
ending anchor
data
data
data
```

Output:

```
name1 12345
data
data
data


name1 name2 12345987
data
data
data
```

Answer (score 0):

Two tips

1. Process files line by line instead of slurping
2. Use the [Range Operator `..`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators) for logic that spans multiple lines

The following is a clean up of your script that works as you desire:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $file = 'list_2.txt';

#open my $fh, '<', $file;
my $fh = \*DATA;

while (<$fh>) {
    if ( my $range = /^Start Anchor/ .. /^ending anchor/ ) {
        if ( $range =~ /E/ ) {
            print "\n";
        } elsif ( $range > 1 ) {
            chomp;
            print ' ' if $range > 2;
            print;
        }
    } else {
        print;
    }
}

__DATA__
Start Anchor
Name1
12345
ending anchor
data
data
data

Start Anchor
name1
name2
12345987
ending anchor
data
data
data
```

Outputs:

```
Name1 12345
data
data
data

name1 name2 12345987
data
data
data
```